# TextInputLayout hint color when disabled is not as expected

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have a `TextInputLayout` as seen below, the problem I'm facing is that when `MyTextInput` (which is a `TextInputEditText`) is disabled, the color I'm setting in `hintTextAppearance` **does not apply**, **but it does** when the input is enabled.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    .....
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/myTextLabel">

    <com.test.ui.widget.MyTextInput
        ...
        android:enabled="@{viewActions.isInputEnabled}" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This is the style :

```
<style name="myTextLabel">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_smaller</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/gold.dark</item>
</style>
```

I've went through several questions here and applied different approaches, but nothing seems to work.